# I want to get date when I find Extreme Fear after Extreme Greed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I have 4 columns:

- `timestamp` in which I have date
- `fear_greed` in which fear and greed index value
- `value_classification` I have only two classes extreme fear and extreme greed
- `close` is price

so I want to get the date in which first extreme fear comes also the date on which extreme greed comes

```
 timestamp  fear_greed value_classification        close
2018-02-02          15         Extreme Fear  8830.750000
2018-02-04          24         Extreme Fear  8277.009766
2018-02-05          11         Extreme Fear  6955.270020
2019-05-11          76        Extreme Greed  7204.771484
2019-05-13          78        Extreme Greed  7814.915039
2019-05-14          78        Extreme Greed  7994.416016
2019-07-15          16         Extreme Fear 10895.089844
2019-07-17          19         Extreme Fear  9693.802734
2019-07-24          20         Extreme Fear  9811.925781
2020-07-28          76        Extreme Greed 10912.823242
```

Output required

```
 timestamp  fear_greed value_classification        close
2018-02-02          15         Extreme Fear  8830.750000
2019-05-11          76        Extreme Greed  7204.771484
2019-07-15          16         Extreme Fear 10895.089844
2020-07-28          76        Extreme Greed 10912.823242
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve]  Try to export your example `df.to dict()` because nobody really likes to type things, if it also could be provided in a propper format ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current `value_classification` and the previous one:

```
out = df[df['value_classification'].ne(df['value_classification'].shift())]
print(out)

# Output
   timestamp  fear_greed value_classification         close
0 2018-02-02          15         Extreme Fear   8830.750000
3 2019-05-11          76        Extreme Greed   7204.771484
6 2019-07-15          16         Extreme Fear  10895.089844
9 2020-07-28          76        Extreme Greed  10912.823242
```